# Can't import stringutils on Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I'm trying the basics with the following code:

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/stringutils;
 
public function main() {
    string str1 = "Comparing String";
    string str2 = "cOmpaRinG sTrinG";
    io:print("String '" + str1 + "' and '" + str2 + "' are");
    if (stringutils:equalsIgnoreCase(str1, str2)) {
        io:println(" equal");
    } else {
        io:println(" not equal");
    }
}
```

But I get an error:

```
caio@german_shepherd test % bal run ./string.bal
Compiling source
    string.bal
ERROR [string.bal:(2:1,2:30)] cannot resolve module 'ballerina/stringutils'
ERROR [string.bal:(8:9,8:49)] undefined function 'equalsIgnoreCase'
ERROR [string.bal:(8:9,8:49)] undefined module 'stringutils'
error: compilation contains errors
caio@german_shepherd test % bal -v
Ballerina Swan Lake Beta 2
Language specification 2021R1
Update Tool 1.3.5
caio@german_shepherd test % sudo bal dist use slbeta2
Password:
'slbeta2' is the current active distribution version
```

I see the same error while editing the code on VSC.
What is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ballerina/stringutils` module is removed with Swan Lake Beta 1 release. The "regex" related APIs were moved to `ballerina/regex` [1] module and rest of the APIs are available at langlib string library [2].

Therefore we need to update your code sample as follows:

```
import ballerina/io;
 
public function main() {
    string str1 = "Comparing String";
    string str2 = "cOmpaRinG sTrinG";
    io:print("String '" + str1 + "' and '" + str2 + "' are");
    if ('string:equalsIgnoreCaseAscii(str1, str2)) {
        io:println(" equal");
    } else {
        io:println(" not equal");
    }
}
```

[1] https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/regex/latest

[2] https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.string/latest